# What are the different types of Rajyog in astrology?

Tags: astrology, navagraha

In astrology, there are multiple [Rajyog based on placement of planets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raja_yoga_(Hindu_astrology)).

What are those? How are those formed in the birth chart?

Are there any negative Rajyogs?

The Wikipedia article is too long and too technical. Can someone explain this in simple language?
If list is too long, if someone just list down few important ones with how those are formed and if they are negative or positive, that should be enough.

Comment: Hi! the raja-yoga tag is for a different purpose. It refers to raja-yoga the yoga technique but ur Q is about rajyogs of astrology. So I have removed that tag :) Also, to my knowledge rajyogs have only positive effect on the native.

Comment: The list is quite big. Is there anything specific you want to check ? The link in one one of the comments is more or less complete. Also there are no raja yogas

Comment: @Carmensandiego: If list is long, if someone just list down few important ones with how those are formed and if they are negative or positive, that should be enough.